# Modify one list according to degeneracies of another

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, each with four elements, let's say

```
listA = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9}
listB = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}
```

Notice that the second and third element of `listA` are the same. I would like to modify `listB` by summing the corresponding elements, such that in the end I get

```
listB = {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}
```

where `0.5 = 0.2 + 0.3`. In general I could have three or four degenerate members of `listA`, and I would like to have some cutoff for treating the floating point values of `listA` as being the same (e.g. $10^{-15}$). I could also have no degeneracy in `listA`, in which case `listB` should be unmodified. I haven't found a nice way to do this without resorting to loops and `If` statements.

Comment: Since nobody asked: are the degenerate elements always adjacent to each other, or can they be separated by other elements?

Comment: @J.M. we can assume that `listA` is sorted from least to greatest, so they are always adjacent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here’s a simple way:

```
listA /. Merge[Thread[listA -> listB], Total]
{0.1`, 0.5`, 0.5`, 0.4`}
```

Comment: This is very nice

Answer (score 9):

## TL;DR

```
listA = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9}
listB = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}
threshold = 10^-15;

(*Revised and better way thanks to J.M.*)
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "Unitize"] := (1 - Unitize[Chop[Outer[Plus, list1, -list1], threshold]]).list2

(*Old*)
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "Boole"] := Outer[Boole[Chop[#1 - #2, threshold] == 0] &, list1, list1].list2

(*Run-Length Block Diagonal Matrix*)
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "RLBDM"] := Block[
  {runs, runLengthMatrixList},
  runs = Split[list1, Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-15 &];
  runLengthMatrixList = ConstantArray[1, Length@# {1, 1}] & /@ runs;
  (*see below*) matrixDirectSum[runLengthMatrixList].list2
]

(*SequencePosition*)
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "SequencePosition"] := Block[
  {temp = list2, pos = SplitBy[SequencePosition[list1, {x_, (x_) ..}], #[[2]] &][[;; , 1]]},
  (temp[[Span @@ #]] = Total@Take[list2, #]) & /@ pos;
  temp
]

f[listA, listB, Method -> #] & /@ {"Boole", "Unitize", "RLBDM", "SequencePosition"}
```

> {{0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}}

## The Long Part

*WE CaN seE* that $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 w \\
 x \\
 y \\
 z \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 w \\
 x + y \\
 x + y \\
 z \\
\end{array}
\right)$ where the block-, sub-matrix of 1s comes from the positions (or position and length of the run since they will always be adjacent) of the duplicate elements.  Now it's just a matter of creating that matrix from the secondary vector.

### Outer Product

One way of going about making the transformation is using the outer product `Outer` to element-wise identify the entries that are within the threshold of each other.

```
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "Boole"] := Outer[Boole[Chop[#1 - #2, 10^-15] == 0] &, list1, list1].list2
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "Unitize"] :=  (*Thanks J.M.*) (1 - Unitize[Chop[Outer[Plus, list1, -list1], 10^-15]]).list2
```

### Matrix Direct Sum and Run-Length Block Diagonal Matrix

Another method is to take advantage of the fact that the duplicate elements will always be adjacent, thus creating runs of identical entries.  The length of these runs (including runs of length 1) is exactly the dimension of the block matrix that appears on the diagonal of our transformation.  Then we can compute the [direct sum of these matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum) (i.e. a block diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the run-matrices).

```
matrixDirectSum[matList : {__?MatrixQ}] := SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[Transpose@Range[1, Length@matList {1, 1}] -> matList // Thread] // Normal

f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "RLBDM"] := Block[
  {runs, runLengthMatrixList},
  runs = Split[list1, Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-15 &] (*Partition the list into runs of entries that are within the threshold*);
  runLengthMatrixList = ConstantArray[1, Length@# {1, 1}] & /@ runs (*Create a list of square 1-matrices with dimension equal to the length of the run*);
  matrixDirectSum[runLengthMatrixList].list2
]
```

`` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` found via tumbling down the rabbit hole of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32978/46490) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/46490) and finally to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99577/46490).  I have also had this nagging feeling that the block matrix could be constructed more directly via [Kronecker sums and/or Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Kronecker_sum).

### SequencePosition

In doing something else, using [SequencePosition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) also popped into my head.

```
f[list1_, list2_, Method -> "SequencePosition"] := Block[
  {temp = list2, pos = SplitBy[SequencePosition[list1, {x_, (x_) ..}], #[[2]] &][[;; , 1]]},
  (temp[[Span @@ #]] = Total@Take[list2, #]) & /@ pos;
  temp
]
```

This even works as below because it takes and adds the orthogonal rows of the identity matrix.

### Just the matrix

In any case, we can also implement the functionality to give just the matrix.

```
f[list_, m : (Method -> _)] := f[list, IdentityMatrix@Length@list, m]
f[listA, Method -> "RLBDM"]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

This is also the form of an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of the graph representation of the matrix.

### Timing Comparison

```
With[
  {lists = Round[RandomReal[1, {2, #}], 0.1]},
    First@RepeatedTiming[
      f[## & @@ lists, Method -> #];] & /@ {"Boole", "Unitize", "RLBDM", "SequencePosition"}
] & /@ Range[100, 1000, 100] // Transpose
ListLogPlot[
  %,
  DataRange -> {100, 1000}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Boole", "Unitize", "RLBDM", "SequencePosition"}, 
  Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"List length", "Time [s]"}
] // Rasterize
```

Turns out the RLBDM method is at least an order of magnitude quicker than the others!  And as expected, `SequencePosition` is slowest at higher lengths, no doubt due to pattern matching.

[image]

Comment: I like this, very clever

Comment: I would modify this to `(1 - Unitize[Chop[Outer[Plus, listA, -listA], 10^-15]]) . listB`.

Comment: Chop[#1 - #2, 10^-15] == 0 means close enough. Boole[...] means bool to 0 and 1, Outer[xx, listA, listA] means for each element, compare itself with other elements. So get a 0-1 matrix, each means one element has any position same with others. . to apply to listB.

Comment: @J.M. There's the `Unitize` I was originally trying to use.  For some reason my mind couldn't think of a way to make `0 -> 1 && 1 -> 0`.  Yay arithmetic!

Comment: (+1) A great answer. I learned a lot. But do the values within a given tolerance in alist have to be adjacent?  `alistX={2.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9}` `blistX={4.4,0.2,0.1, 0.3,0.4}` and `Outer[Boole[Chop[#1 - #2, 10^(-4)] == 0] &, alistX, alistX].blistX` gives (in my hands) `{4.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4}`. But perhaps I am missing something very obvious?

Comment: @user the OP confirmed that degenerate elements can be assumed to be adjacent, but I guess generalizing the implementation so that assumption is unnecessary would be very interesting.

Comment: I think what I am trying to say is that `{{1, 0, 0, 0},{0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}.{w,x,y,z}` gives `{w, x + z, y, x + z}`  and (say) `1-Unitize@Outer[Plus,{1,10,2,10}, -{1,10,2,10}]` will give the appropriate matrix (identical elements do not need to be contiguous?)

Answer (score 4):

My attempt for your problem is as follows:

```
ReplaceByDegeneracy[listA_, listB_] := Block[{dupA, posA, extractB, arrayB},
dupA = Mean[Flatten[Map[If[#[[1]] === #[[2]], #, Nothing] &, 
DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[listA, {2}]]]]];
posA = Position[listA, dupA];
extractB = Extract[listB, posA];
arrayB = Array[Total[Extract[listB, posA]] &, Length[extractB]];
ReplaceAll[Thread[extractB -> arrayB]][listB]]
```

Test:

```
ReplaceByDegeneracy[listA, listB]
(*{0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}*)
```

Also:

```
listC = {0.3,0.6,0.6,0,6};
ReplaceByDegeneracy[listC, listB]
(*{0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** Better algorithm for detecting consecutive runs

(Thanks to @user1066 for detecting this shortcoming)

```
threshold = 10^-2;
alist = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.605, 0.9, 0.8, 0.095, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3};
blist = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1};
```

It becomes cumbersome with `Differences` that I originally used, so I will use `Split` with a similar split function.

```
alistSplit = 
 Split[alist, Between[#1, {#2 - threshold, #2 + threshold}] &]
```

> {{0.3}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.605}, {0.9}, {0.8}, {0.095, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.3}}

```
degenPos = 
 Flatten[Length /@ alistSplit /. {1 -> 0, 
    x_Integer :> ConstantArray[1, x]}]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}

If `blist` were split, it would look like:

```
blistSplit = TakeList[blist, Length /@ alistSplit]
```

> {{0.1}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.1}, {0.4}, {0.6}, {0.5, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.1}}

and the individual totals would be:

```
Total@## & /@ blistSplit
```

> {0.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 1., 0.1}

Putting it together:

```
clist = Flatten@
  MapThread[
   ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {Total@## & /@ blistSplit, 
    Length /@ alistSplit}]
```

For visualization:

```
arrows = degenPos /. {0 -> "\[Cross]", 
   1 -> Style["\[UpDownArrow]", Bold, Red]}

Grid@{alist, arrows, blist, arrows, 
  MapAt[Framed[#, Background -> Yellow] &, clist, 
   Position[degenPos, 1]]}
```

[image]

---

**Original attempt** (not working properly for consecutive runs)

```
threshold = 10^-4;
SeedRandom[9];
alist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 15]/10.0 + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}];
blist = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 15]/10.0 + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}];

degenPos = ({#, # + 1} & /@ Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Position[Differences[alist], 
    x_ /; Between[x, {-threshold, +threshold}]])
```

> {{5, 6}, {13, 14}}

```
tots = Total@blist[[#]] & /@ degenPos
```

> {1.41283, 1.31283}

For visualization:

```
arrows = ReplacePart[
  ConstantArray["\[Cross]", 
   Length@alist], # -> Style["\[UpDownArrow]", Bold, Red] & /@ 
   Flatten@degenPos]

clist = ReplacePart[blist, 
  Flatten[#, 1] &@(Thread[#] & /@ 
     Rule @@@ Transpose[{degenPos, tots}])]

Grid@{alist, arrows, blist, arrows, 
  MapAt[Framed[#, Background -> Yellow] &, clist, 
   List /@ Flatten@degenPos]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user1066 for pointing it out. I should have been more diligent. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could write:

```
listA = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9};
listB = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
Total[Map[listB[[#]] &, Nearest[listA -> "Index", listA, {∞, 10^-15}], {-1}], {2}]
(* {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4} *)
```

Or more simply:

```
Total[Nearest[listA -> listB, listA, {∞, 10^-15}], {2}]
(* {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add my personal solution in addition to the other excellent answers.

```
s=Length/@Split[listA,Abs[#1-#2]<10^(-5)&];
listB=Flatten@Table[ConstantArray[Total@i,Length@i],{i,TakeList[listB,s]}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9};

b = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};

CLS = Internal`CopyListStructure;
```

Using `Replace`, `CopyListStructure` and `SequenceCases`

```
Replace[
 CLS[SequenceCases[a, {x_ ...}], b],
 x : {__} :> Splice @ Table[Total @ x, Length @ x],
 {1}]
```

> {0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}

A more complicated case

```
a = {0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5};

b = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0, 0.4, 0.1, 1.0};

Replace[
 CLS[SequenceCases[a, {x_ ...}], b],
 x : {__} :> Splice@Table[Total@x, Length@x],
 {1}]
```

> {0.1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.4, 1.1, 1.1}